# Check the duplicate objects in array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to find the duplicate value in the array of objects and return true value in es6 function.

```js
arrayOne = [{
    agrregatedVal: "count",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "count",
    value: "Pay Date"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "count",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Signature"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Pay Date"
  }]
```

Above is the structure of the json

Here i have two object which are duplicate:

```js
{
  agrregatedVal: "min",
  value: "Employee Full Name"
}, {
  agrregatedVal: "min",
  value: "Employee Full Name"
}
```

and remaining are not concerned as both values of each object are different.

If each object value is duplicate of another object of same array then it should return true.

I tried in this way:-

```js
this.arrayOne = this.arrayOne.filter((thing, index, self) => {
  return index === self.findIndex((t) => {
    return t.agrregatedVal === thing.agrregatedVal && t.value === thing.value;
  });
});
```

it dint work, how to return true if object of each value is same of another object.

Comment: You never return anything from your callback function. It should be `return index === ...`, or you should remove the curly braces.

Comment: i tried to remove curly braces it still dint work for me

Comment: You must do the same for the inner callback too. https://jsfiddle.net/twox60dm/

Comment: it removes the duplicate value and returns the array but i just need the boolean value instead of array

Comment: which boolean value? Explain clearly what your method should do: "my method should return true when...". The code you posted creates a filtered array.

Comment: @vinuta wrap it in the another method and return true of false if filter returned array.

Comment: i just need if there is duplicate object then i need to display a error message "that the object already exists in array", i don't want to remove the object from array

Comment: @MaihanNijat i dint get you

Comment: I don't think the method which i tried is correct one @JB Nizet

Comment: So "my method should return true when there is at least one object that is duplicated in the array"? Is that right? Use every() instead of filter(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: @JBNizet yes method should return true when there is at least one object that is duplicated in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few things :

1) Has Duplicates :

> it dint work, how to return true if object of each value is same of another object.

```
const dict=arrayOne.map((item,pos)=>{
  return item.agrregatedVal+":"+item.value;
});


hasDuplicate=dict.some(function(item, id){ 
     if(dict.indexOf(item) != id)
       return item;
});

console.log(hasDuplicate);
```

2) Remove Duplicates :

```
 unique = [...new Set(arrayOne.map(a => a.agrregatedVal+ "':'"+ a.value))];
```

Now, you can construct back your object with these

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const arrayOne = [{
    agrregatedVal: "count",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "count",
    value: "Pay Date"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "count",
    value: "Employee Full Name"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Signature"
  },
  {
    agrregatedVal: "min",
    value: "Pay Date"
  }]

function hasDuplicate(arrayOne) {
  const newArray = arrayOne.filter((thing, index, self) => index === self.findIndex(t => t.agrregatedVal === thing.agrregatedVal && t.value === thing.value));

  return newArray.length < arrayOne.length;
}

console.log(hasDuplicate(arrayOne));
```

hasDupliecate will return true if there is/are duplicates

Answer (score 1):

**De-duplicating an array**

Consider the following implementation:

```js
const initialArray = [
  {agrregatedVal: "count", value: "Employee Full Name"},
  {agrregatedVal: "min", value: "Employee Full Name"},
  {agrregatedVal: "min", value: "Employee Full Name"},
];

const dedupedArray = [
  ...new Set(initialArray.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)))
].map(itemJson => JSON.parse(itemJson));

console.log(dedupedArray);
```

1. Every item in the original array is converted to Json string
2. The strings are dumped inside a `Set` which discards the duplicates
3. The `Set`, which now contains only unique Json strings, is converted back into an array
4. The objects are recreated back from the strings

---

**A function which determines if an object is duplicated inside an array**

I think what you actually want to achieve is to have a function that determines if an object is a duplicate of another object in an array, right?

```js
const array = [
  {agrregatedVal: "count", value: "Employee Full Name"},
  {agrregatedVal: "min", value: "Employee Full Name"},
  {agrregatedVal: "min", value: "Employee Full Name"},
];

const isDuplicate = (itemA, array) => !!array.find(itemB => itemA !== itemB && JSON.stringify(itemA) === JSON.stringify(itemB));

console.log(isDuplicate(array[1], array))
```